# GORM dynamic get Method

Tags: grails

I was asking myself if it's possible to reduce my code from

```
User.get(Long.valueOf(params.userid))
```

to

```
User.get(params.userid)
```

So the parameters are Strings and  the ID of the DomainClasses are mostly Longs, so my idea was to override the get Method and dynamicly find out the datatype of the ID from the domainClass and try to cast the given parameter if necessary.

FYI I'm using grails 2.5.4

Is there any opportunity to do this?

Comment: there is also params.long('userid')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been working that way since Grails 2.1 or alike. The `get()` method can be invoked directly:

```
def inst = MyDomain.get params.id
```

and the conversion `String -> Long` is performed automatically